# Database hosts array is empty. (SQL: select * from "banners")

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, heroku, web-deployment

```
$DATABASE_URL=parse_url('postgres://fqnpjjhewnbejh:119f97d0d51c4ff03ec896813878b9e3bb3d588ccb27dd257e4106cfadf22b09@ec2-54-152-185-191.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d9dmcpo4dupmpl');

 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),

        'pgsql' => [
            
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => $DATABASE_URL['ec2-54-152-185-191.compute-1.amazonaws.com'],
            'port' => $DATABASE_URL['5432'],
            'database' => ltrim($DATABASE_URL['postgres://fqnpjjhewnbejh:119f97d0d51c4ff03ec896813878b9e3bb3d588ccb27dd257e4106cfadf22b09@ec2-54-152-185-191.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d9dmcpo4dupmpl'], "/"),
            'username' => $DATABASE_URL['fqnpjjhewnbejh'],
            'password' => $DATABASE_URL["119f97d0d51c4ff03ec896813878b9e3bb3d588ccb27dd257e4106cfadf22b09"],
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'require',
        ],
```

Comment: `$DATABASE_URL` ill have keys like e.g. `$DATABASE_URL['host']` not the keys you've put there

Comment: Please provide me the keys...!!

Comment: They're all listed [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) under "Return values"

Comment: Rohit, please see my answer, as there is an action you need to complete.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested the way to resolve this is by using the actual array keys which are generated when you use the function parse_url();

Keys can be any of the following, and for ease I've added the values you'd get;

```
scheme: "postgres"
host: "ec2-54-152-185-191.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
port: 5432
user: "fqnpjjhewnbejh"
pass: "119f97d0d51c4ff03ec896813878b9e3bb3d588ccb27dd257e4106cfadf22b09"
path: "/d9dmcpo4dupmpl"
query: {not set}
fragment: {not set}
```

As such you will need to update your code as follows

```
'host' => $DATABASE_URL['host'],
// etc ...
```

However, it is now **VERY IMPORTANT** that you change the username and password of your postgres instance, as you've posted these on a public site for all to see.